# EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

When I run my code which is totally fine I get an error saying " EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY" and some parts of the app turns red I don't know why

```
[This is the code screenshot][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX5Qn.jpg

Comment: Hey, Ahmed! This means you have an exception, which is an error. Now which is the specific type of exception will be written at the top of those numbered lines along with this info, and in this case is also written on the phone screen. The real error is `Too few positional arguments. 1 required, 0 given`. But it seems to be on the appbar, still I don't see an error. Try reading further up on the first few lines to see where it is, there will be a link to one of your lines of code probably.

Comment: I noticed something weird, whenever I create a Flutter project and just run the basic main.dart without editing anything it pops up an error so can it be the SDK?

Comment: Oh, that's weird. It could be indeed. Try running `flutter upgrade`, `flutter doctor` and maybe if it doesn't work, reinstalling flutter.